# eval and anchor tag href in a text label property ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, eval, anchor, string.format

I have been trying to get these running looking at lots of different samples but with no luck.

To me it seems it's ok but what am I missing here?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="<%# String.Format("<a href=http://localhost/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/temp&rs:Command=Render&id={0}>link</a>", Eval("ID")) %>" Width="100px" visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

"With no luck" is not a descriptive error.

`<%#` is for databinding expression only. So have you called `Page.DataBind()` or at least `Label1.DataBind()` in codebehind?

You could also try

```
Text='<%= String.Format("<a href=http://localhost/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/temp&rs:Command=Render&id={0}>link</a>", Eval("ID")) %>'
```

Apart from that, why not doing such things in codebehind only, so you don't have issues like this?

Comment: You are right, it is not very descriptive. What I meant is that I tried different ways to populate the Text property using the href and Eval in different ways. And yes, DataBind() is called and if I do not fix it like it is now, then I will try to do it in the codebehind, but I wanted to give it a try

Comment: btw, that was the issue, the double quotes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# String.Format("<a href=http://localhost/reportserver/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/temp&rs:Command=Render&id={0}>link</a>", Eval("ID")) %>' Width="100px" visible="true"></asp:Label>
```

you shouldn't use Text="something". you should use Text='something'